# Find exact url match

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find exact url mach in url list using with Regular Expression .

```
                string url = @"http://web/P02/Draw/V/Service.svc";
                string myword = @"http://web/P02/Draw/V/Service.svc http://web/P02/Draw/V/Service.svc?wsdl";
                string pattern = @"(^|\s)" + url + @"(\s|$)";
                Match match = Regex.Match(pattern, myword);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    myword = Regex.Replace(myword, pattern, "pattern");
                }
```

But the pattern returns no result.

What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: Why don't you split `myword` by space and then use linq to select it?

Comment: you don't need regex to find an exact match. string.Contains() will work just fine.

Comment: But won't check whether there's space on either side.

Comment: Regex is powerful when you need to match patterns. You are asking for an exact match. You don't need a regex for an exact match. Exact matches are made with `Equals` or as Hardrada said: `Contains`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing wrong arguments to `Regex.Match` method. You need to swap arguments like this>

```
Match match = Regex.Match(myword,pattern);
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange formatting aside, here is a pattern to match each individual URL in your list.

```
Pattern = "http://([a-zA-Z]|/|[0-9])*\.svc";
```

Frankly, I don't think you're having issues with syntax or implementation. If you want to tweak the expression I wrote above, this is the place to do it: [Online RegEx Tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: RePierre's argument applies as well - apparently you do have syntactic issues.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Linq on the string collection (when splitted by a space)

```
myword.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Equals(url)).Single().Replace(url, "pattern");
```

Comment: this is not even necessary. By virtue of existing or not existing, using Replace only will work without having to first check for the strings presence. That being said, I up-vote you for suggesting using equals and replace instead of killing it with an un-necessary regex.

Comment: You are right, that a simple replace would be sufficient. but maybe he wants to know if there will be a replace action.

Answer (score 0):

- You've got your arguments the wrong way around, as has been pointed out
- `.` in a regular expression pattern is a special character, so you need to escape `url` when you use it to build pattern - you can use `Regex.Escape(url)`
- You don't need to check the match is a success before performing the replacement, unless you have other logic that depends on whether the match was a success.